# Correct initializer list when inheriting from virtual base class without creating diamond problem

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, base-class, virtual-inheritance

So I get that when you create a diamond in inheritance the most derived class needs to explicitly call the constructor of the virtual class's sub-objects in its initializer list.

But what about classes that inherit from a virtual class without that inheritance creating a diamond itself? **e.g. Bow inherits from virtual base class Weapon, does Bow need a call to Object's constructor in its initializer list too and why?**

I've become a bit tangled with all the classes inheritances and initializer lists and I just need to clear things up first before continuing and remove any unnecessary calls in my initializer lists.

Object's constructor takes a sf::Vector2f which is two floats. So far I've had Movable, Weapon and Projectile as virtual base classes since they are part of the diamond.

[image]

```cpp
// sf::Vector2f is an SFML data type which consists of two floats

class Object
{
private:
    sf::Vector2f m_pos;
public:
    Object(sf::Vector2f start_pos) {m_pos = start_pos;};
}

class Movable : virtual public Object
{
public:
    Movable(sf::Vector2f start_pos) : Object(start_pos) { ... };
}

class Weapon : virtual public Object
{
public:
    Weapon(float shotDelay, bool isStealth) : Object(sf::Vector2f(0,0)) { ... };
}

class Projectile : public Movable
{
public:
    Projectile (sf::Vector2f startPos, int damage) : Movable(startPos) { ... };
}

class Bow : public Weapon
{
public:
    Bow() : Weapon(BOW_SHOT_DELAY, BOW_STEALTH) { ... };
}

class Grenade : public Weapon, public Projectile
{
public:
    Grenade() : Weapon(GRENADE_SHOT_DELAY, GRENADE_STEALTH) {};//for Weapon
    Grenade(sf::Vector2f startPos) : Projectile(startPos, GRENADE_DAMAGE);//for Projectile
}
```

Comment: Please show your code ([mcve]). If you inherit then you may want to call the constructor of the base class, whether virtual or not

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it wasnt a good one. It helped me to identify a hole in my understanding but it didnt help anything for your particular situation. I kindly ask you again to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to initialise every direct or indirect virtual base class, regardless of having or nit having a diamond.

Comment: okay give me some time to write a minimal example for you, I thought it was something that could be answered without code

Comment: my actual class code is split into header files and implementations separately

Comment: Whether you find your answer or not, complex multi-inheritance hierarchies like this are going to cause a headache. Given that your example is probably a small slice if your game, I recommend considering a pattern like Entity-Component-System (ECS) to simplify your code by separating data, capabilities and interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, the helpful comments, playing around and tidying up my code I figured out the answer and what was going wrong. I was supplying the Object constructor with a default argument so it was being called that way whether I included the call in the initializer list of a class or not.

A class that inherits from a virtual base class **must include calls the constructors of the virtual base class's sub-objects in its initializer list if they do not have default constructors**.

So in my example, since Bow inherits from virtual base class Weapon which inherits from Object, its initializer list will look like this:

```
Bow::Bow() : Object(BOW_STARTING_POS), Weapon(BOW_SHOT_DELAY, BOW_STEALTH)
{
  //constructor code
}
```

For completeness I'm adding what the Grenade initializer lists should be when there is no default constructor:

```
Grenade::Grenade() : Object(GRENADE_STARTING_POS), Weapon(GRENADE_SHOT_DELAY, GRENADE_STEALTH)
{
  //weapon constructor code
}

Grenade::Grenade() : Object(GRENADE_STARTING_POS), Projectile(GRENADE_STARTING_POS, GRENADE_DAMAGE)
{
  // projectile constructor code
}
```

P.S. grenade is split into two constructors because my design required it that way. In a different case where you only need one constructor for a class inheriting from two virtual base classes, one initializer list can contain all the constructor calls as such:

```
Grenade::Grenade() : Object(GRENADE_STARTING_POS), Projectile(GRENADE_STARTING_POS, GRENADE_DAMAGE), Weapon(GRENADE_SHOT_DELAY, GRENADE_STEALTH)
{
  //constructor code
}
```